# Why is this tikz-picture not compiling

Tags: tikz-pgf, automata

I am new to Latex and especially to Latex-Beamer.
I try to make this tikz-picture compile, but it does not work. Would anybody be so kind to help me fix it?
Thanks in advance!

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
    automata,
    positioning,
    quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[t]{}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.4, transform shape][
            - > , >= stealth,
            shorten >=1pt ,
            node distance =2.5 cm ,
            initial text = ,
            semithick ]
            \tikzstyle{accepting}=[green, text = black, accepting by double]
            \tikzstyle{non-acc} = [red, text = black]
            \node[state, initial, accepting] (q) {$ \varepsilon_1 $};
            \node[state, non-acc](q0) [right = 2cm of q]{$ 0_2 $}
            \node[state, draw = none](d)[above =1 cm of q] {};
            \path[->]   
            (q)   edge [above] node {0} (q0)
            (q) edge [right] node {1} (d)
            ;
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Rmano: Unfortunately, it still does not compile

Comment: yes, that was just one ;-) --- answered

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have several syntax errors.

1. You have `...[scale = 0.4, transform shape][ ...`  so you close and reopen an optional argument, but `tikzpicture` just accepts one;
2. You forgot a semicolon in the  second `\node`
3. You wrote `- >` instead of `->`

Moreover, you are using a (very) deprecated syntax for styles.

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
    automata,
    positioning,
    quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[t]{}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.4, transform shape,
            -> , >= stealth,
            shorten >=1pt ,
            node distance =2.5 cm ,
            initial text = ,
            semithick ]
            \tikzset{accepting/.style={green, text = black, accepting by double},
                non-acc/.style={red, text = black}}
            \node[state, initial, accepting] (q) {$ \varepsilon_1 $};
            \node[state, non-acc](q0) [right = 2cm of q]{$ 0_2 $};
            \node[state, draw = none](d)[above =1 cm of q] {};
            \path[->]
            (q)   edge [above] node {0} (q0)
            (q) edge [right] node {1} (d)
            ;
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for answering!

Comment: How would you do it in a less deprecated way?

Comment: @sorry, I did that in my answer, with `\tikzset{name/.style={...}}` --- `\tikzstyle` is deprecated since 2.0, I think. And you can even avoid the `\tikzset`, and putting the style definition in the `[...]` of the `tikzpicture` (If they are local to this picture, obviously; if the `tikzset`-styles are for all the document, they should go in the preamble.)

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

I would exploit all loaded libraries and correctly define styles for image's elements (for your errors see nice (+1)  @Rmano answer):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, automata,
                positioning,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Title of frame}
    \begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5, transform shape,
node distance = 24mm, on grid,
    semithick,
    shorten > = 1pt,
            > = Stealth,
    initial text = {}]
\node[state,initial, double, draw=green]        (q0)    {$\varepsilon_1$};
\node[state, draw=red, right=of q0]  (q1)    {$0_1$};
%
\path[->] (q0) edge ["0"] (q1)
          (q0) edge ["1" '] ++ (0,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In the case, that you like that image is at top left side of slide, then add option `[t]` to `\begin{frame}` and remove `center` environment.

** Addendum:**
By defining initial node style, the image code become shorter:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, automata,
                positioning,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title of frame}
    \begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8, transform shape,
node distance = 24mm, on grid,
    semithick,
    outer sep = 1.6pt,      % new
            > = Stealth,
initial/.append style = {initial text = {}, % new
                         double, double distance=1.6pt, draw=green}
                    ]
\node[state,initial]        (q0)    {$\varepsilon_1$};
\node[state, draw=red, right=of q0]  (q1)    {$0_1$};
%
\path[->] (q0) edge ["0"] (q1)
          (q0) edge ["1" '] ++ (0,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]